# Jmeter tool-Graph results

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter tool-Is there any way to create custom charts/graphs that is,in which virtual users,response transfer speed,errors,warnings and passed request all should come together in a single graph through which we can get better idea of crashing point of server. As now,there are individual graphs to see the transfer speed ,virtual users etc,So can we create custom graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this, it should answer your needs:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/CompositeGraph/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.I need one more help as I have entered 500 to be the number of thread group and ramp up time to be 120 seconds but when the report is generated,the virtual users count is only 15 or in composite graph-active threads over time is raised to near about 12 .So I am bit confuse active threads counts.Because the data(threads) or numbers that I filled in test plan before test is different and after result is different.What about scaled values in graph?and x10?Something related to threads?